# creating a sidebar selector with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

so I think what i'm trying to do should be simple, in logic at least. I created a custom field in Advance Custom Fields that has a drop down to select a sidebar. My Site has X number of sidebars and I need to be selectable via that page you are editing.

So in ACF I created a dropdown with this.

'sidebar-main' : Main Sidebar

'sidebar-about' : About Sidebar

'advocacy-sidebar' : Advocacy Sidebar

'military-sidebar' : Military Sidebar

'families-sidebar' : Families Sidebar

'members-sidebar' : Members Sidebar

'contact-sidebar' : Contact Sidebar

and tried using this code in all page templates

```
<?php $sidebar = the_field('sidebar');
    dynamic_sidebar($sidebar);
?>
```

Logicly I feel that should work. I set a function to get the field then insert that into the dynamic sidebar code?

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you actually encountering a specific issue? If the latter, please edit with the error, and minimal-but-complete code to reproduce the error. If the former...try it and found out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php 
    // Get page-specific sidebar.
    $sidebar = get_field('sidebar');
    dynamic_sidebar($sidebar);
?>
```